# Delete a file in download directory

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I have been helped to create an app few months ago and i'm trying to make it evolved by myself and it's not as easy as I would like.

I would like to delete a file that has been created in the download directory.
I'm using this folder as a cache folder to share a sound stocked in my app.
Here is the sample for the share option (which is well working, except i do not understand where i'm supposed to put the `outputFile.delete();` line...)

```
case R.id.partage:
            File outputFile = new File("");
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(((Sound) adapter.getItem(index)).getMpsound());

            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(buffer);
                File outputDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                outputFile = new File(outputDir, getResources().getResourceEntryName(((Sound) adapter.getItem(index)).getMpsound()) + ".mp3");
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                os.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", outputFile));
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\"" + ((Sound) adapter.getItem(index)).getTitre_show() + "\" shared by my app");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
            return true;
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sharing your file to other apps, you can't delete your file until that other app read your file. And there is nothing that can tell you that other has done with reading your file. You can do batch delete. For example, you can delete all the files together which are shared 1 and more hour before the current time. But for that, you have to create your file such that you should be able to track them. You can keep all your file in a common folder in the download directory to make it easy to track those files. If you need help for logic and code for batch delete, let me know.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I have changed my way of doing. I made a folder in the directory and I delete all the content in the directory before my method is executed. So there is only 1 permanent file in this folder.